# SAS import excel date format changes

Tags: excel, import, sas

I need to import an excel, the excel has a few columns and the 1st column A is a date column. Column A has the date format DDMMMYYYY e.g. '01Jan2017' and in excel the data type is date type. But when I import it to SAS, all the other columns remain the same data type (numeric, character, etc.) and value. But column A becomes a number e.g. ('42736' for '01Jan2017'). How do I import the data as it is and without converting the data type to other types?

```
libname out '/path';

proc import out=out.sas_output_dataset
datafile='/path/excel_file.xlsx'

DBMS=XLSX 
REPLACE;
sheet="Sheet1";

run;
```

Comment: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/068-29.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to know without seeing the data. The below is general information, it may not answer your precise problem.

To avoid common errors you should set mixed=yes in your libname. You may also want to include stringdate=yes statement.

The mixed=yes allows for any out of range excel date values.

stringdates=yes brings all dates into SAS in character format, so you will need to use the input() function to convert this into a SAS date.

Date = input( Date , mmddyy10. )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you import the excel with the import wizard in SAS. Afterwards right-click on the query and extract the code, see here: [SAS Import Query DE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A931t.png)

In the generated code itself you can format each imported column into the desired format.

For the possible format see: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/leforinforref/n0p2fmevfgj470n17h4k9f27qjag.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A value of '42736' for '01Jan2017' is an indication that the column in the Excel file has a mix of cells with date values and cells with string values.  In that case SAS will make the variable character and store the date values as a digit string that represents the raw number excel uses for the date.  To convert '42736' to a date value you need to first convert it to a number and then adjust the number for the difference in the base date used by Excel.

```
date_value = input(date_string,32.) + '30DEC1899'd ;
```

To convert the strings that look like '01JAN2017' use the DATE informat instead.

```
date_value = input(date_string,date11.);
```

You could add logic to do both to handle a column with mixed values.

```
date_value = input(date_string,??date11.);
if missing(date_value) then 
  date_value = input(date_string,??32.) + '30DEC1899'd 
;
```

To have the new variable print the date values in a human readable style attach a date type format to the variable.

```
format date_value date9. ;
```