# Issues with Date format in SAS

Tags: datetime, sas, survival-analysis, ascensor

I am trying to run the survival analysis, while censoring the data based on variables which are in dates. When I upload the complete dataset, all the date variables are imported as characters and i cannot run analysis on them! Format of the dates in all columns are as 08/19/1990.

Here is my code which is simply uploading the data from excel.

```
   **proc import datafile='U:/censor_ami.xlsx'
     out= censor Ami
     dbms=xlsx
     replace;
     options MSGLEVEL=I
     run;*
```

*Please help me sort out this issue!

I need to know how to solve this date format issue in SAS!

Comment: Make sure the COLUMN In the SPREADSHEET That you want SAS to treat as a DATE variable only has cells with DATE values in it.  If ANY of the cells in that column are character then the variable must be character.

Comment: all the value are date forexample   09/12/2023

Comment: It should NOT matter how EXCEL is DISPLAYING the date.  But it does matter if one of the cells has a string instead of an actual date.  Or perhaps even has a string of spaces instead of being empty.   What do the values look like in the SAS variable?  Do they look like '09/12/2023' or do they look like '45269' which is the number that Excel uses for the 9th of December of 2023.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765364/sas-import-excel-date-format-changes

Comment: Date format is  09/23/2023 in excel, when i uplod it in sas it appears in a similar format. I EVEN TRY TO CHANGE THE THE DATE COLUMNS FORMAT IN EXCEL THROUGH FORMAT CELLS BUT STILL IT IS IMPORTED AS A CHARACTER.

Comment: If it looks like '09/23/2023' in Excel and comes over as a character variable in SAS that also looks like '09/23/2023' then it is also a character values in Excel.  Just use the INPUT function as explained in the answer below.  The right informat to use to insure that the strings are interpreted as mm/dd/yyyy is MMDDYY10.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this happens because the date is formatted as a character in Excel. If for some reason you can't get it to work correctly, you can always convert the date yourself in SAS. I personally prefer to try and use the `andydtdte.` date format first since it automatically covers a large number of common dates.

```
data want;
    set have(rename=(date=date2));

    date = input(date2, anydtdte.);

    format date date9.;
    drop date2;
run;
```